# How to get transactionID from payment

Tags: python, paypal

For the following payment that is successfully created:

```
res = requests.post(
    "https://svcs{}.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay/".format("" if settings.STAGE == "production" else ".sandbox"),
    headers=headers, data=params
)

data = res.json()
```

How would I then get the `TransactionID`, which I need to store in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `TransactionID` by sending a call to `/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails/` --

```
params = OrderedDict()
params['requestEnvelope.errorLanguage'] = 'en_US'
params['payKey'] = pay_key
res = requests.post('https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails/', headers=headers, data=params)
transaction_id = res.json()['paymentInfoList']['paymentInfo'][0]['senderTransactionId']
```

Here is the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/